# image recognition and detection algorithm based on depth image

Tags: image, image-processing, kinect, image-recognition

I get a depth camera whose output is grayscale image with depth information. Is there any image recognition and detection algorithm based on depth image (especially for embedded system)?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to detect? If you are talking about general purpose detection, you can always train Haar and HOG on the depth images too

Comment: @ R. S. Nikhil Krishna pedestrian and some obstacles (desks and chairs)in daily life.

Answer (score 0):

Any image processing algorithm can be applied to depth images. Human interpretation is slightly different. Mathematically it's the same as any other 2d image.